# UWP set ImageSource from SplitView

Tags: xaml, uwp, splitpane

I have a litte `SplitView` app an now I will set the `ImageSource` on `page2` from `mySplitpanel`.

How can I get access to all paramaters like **SetSource** or **Visible**?
[image]

Here is my code

**Mainpage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="938.137">
    <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
               CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="150">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel Background="Gray">
                <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE825;"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="MenuButton1_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Button 1" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton2" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE10F;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="MenuButton2_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Button 2" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="MenuButton3" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE1D6;"
                        Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="MenuButton3_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Button 3" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
                     </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <Frame x:Name="myFrame" />
    </SplitView>

</Page>
```

**Mainpage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace App1
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            myFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1));
        }

        private void MenuButton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

                myFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
        }

        private void HamburgerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MySplitView.IsPaneOpen = !MySplitView.IsPaneOpen;
        }

        private void MenuButton2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1)); //Home
        }

        private void MenuButton3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //set image source at page2.myImagePage2
           // ??
        }
    }
}
```

**Page2.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.Page2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="#FFE03535">
        <Image x:Name="myImagePage2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="116" Margin="81,112,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="175" Source="Assets/LockScreenLogo.png"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I want to change the `ImageSource` at **Page2.myImagePage2** from **MenuButton3_Click**

How can I access a function inside `page2`?

The function sets the `Visibilty` of items on `Page2`.
Can I access the function and the items get invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code-behind of `Page2` (`Page2.xaml.cs`) to create a `public` method that will modify the visibility (like `public void HideImage()` or `public void ChangeImageSource()`).

Now to get hold of the current page within the `Click` handler, use the `Frame.Content` property:

```
private void MenuButton3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var page = myFrame.Content as Page2;
   if ( page != null )
   {
      //do something like calling your custom public method
      //page.HideImage();
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay so easy? Thanks! Can i Access the Image Source in the same way? Page.myimage.source or must i cremte a new function that Sets the Image Source and call it?

Comment: You can either do it via a method as described (which is in a way cleaner solution), or you can add a `x:FieldModifier="public"` attribute to the `Image`, which will make the image public and will then be accessible from the `Click` handler like `page.myImagePage2.Source`